# Tensorflow array size doesn't match but it should match

Tags: tensorflow, matplotlib, artificial-intelligence, image-resizing, np

I'm trying to build an ai model which recognizes skin cancer images in tensorflow. Unfortunately I found an error when trying to predict an image it says that shape doesn't match, but I checked it earlier and the shape is the same. It looks like it reshape it when providing it to predict.

Here is the code

```
test = tf.keras.utils.load_img('./thumbnails/malicious/ISIC_0029615.jpg')
test = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(test)
test = tf.image.resize(test, (256, 256))
test /= 255
plt.imshow(test)
print(test.shape)
model.predict(test)
```

And here is the output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  at cell 21, line 7
  at /opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py, line 67, in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
  at /opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py, line 15, in tf__predict_function(iterator)
ValueError: in user code: File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1845, in predict_function * return step_function(self, iterator) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1834, in step_function ** outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,)) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1823, in run_step ** outputs = model.predict_step(data) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1791, in predict_step return self(x, training=False) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 264, in assert_input_compatibility raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" is ' ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_6" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), found shape=(32, 256, 3)
```

If you want to see a full code here is a link to notebook view: [notebook preview](https://datalore.jetbrains.com/notebook/DZ3zldarZq02yv5u4Q5DbU/t1gpBI0zs9LaQbF4PEL1di)

I'm trying to reshape it and also transpose this array because I found this in similar problem but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this code

```
import numpy as np

test = tf.keras.utils.load_img('./thumbnails/malicious/ISIC_0029615.jpg')
test = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(test)
test = tf.image.resize(test, (256, 256))
test /= 255

# Add a new dimension to make it a batch of size 1
test = np.expand_dims(test, axis=0)

plt.imshow(test[0])
print(test.shape)

model.predict(test)
```